# Why text isn't appearing with .text in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the text inside the strong tags. .text did not return anything.

Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='divright']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]//strong")

print(pages.text)
```

Even Inner HTML doesn't show the text in the strong tags, even though its showing up in the HTML below:

InnerHTML:

```html
<strong class="strong text-danger" data-bind="text: pagertext, visible: pagerVisible" style="display: none;"></strong>
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">

    <div class="btn-group" data-bind="visible: pagerVisible" style="">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: function () { changePage('first'); }">
            <i class="icon-step-backward"></i>
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: function () { changePage('prev'); }">
            <i class="icon-backward"></i>
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: function () { changePage('next'); }">
            <i class="icon-forward"></i>
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="visible: pagecount() < 1001, click: function () { changePage('last'); }">
            <i class="icon-step-forward"></i>
        </button>

    </div>

    <strong class="strong text-danger" data-bind="text: pagertext, visible: pagerVisible" style="">Page 1 of 42</strong>

</div>
```

Why are the Pages text not showing up in the HTML attributes or the text yet it's visible when inspecting the webpage?

Comment: looks like the strong tag is being altered dynamically with javascript using pagerVisible variable. When you printed innerHTML, it was in display:none state and has empty innerText. I think some event in the page makes it visible, like a button click or something.. ? see if you can get a screenshot of that page from within python.

Comment: Its showing up on the screenshot. I would imagine its javascript populating it. Is there a way to grab it if it is?

Comment: I added a time.sleep and that solved it. I guess it wasnt getting enough time to load

Comment: time.sleep() is bad practice. Selenium provides this elegant solution:
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someid')))

Comment: Whats the difference?